# How to have all floating windows always on top in awesome-wm

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm

I created a rule for this, but it only works for all existing windows when I restart awesome.

My rule is as follows,

```
{ rule_any = {floating=true
  }, properties = { ontop= true }
},
```

How do I make it so that this happens every time a window is made floating and not just all floating windows during startup?

Answer (score 2):

You can use client.connect_signal like this:

```
client.connect_signal("property::floating", function(c)
    if c.floating then
        c.ontop = true
    else
        c.ontop = false
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing [@ninodemeterko answer](https://superuser.com/a/1726457/1873256), you can achieve the same result with a one-line code.

```
-- Floating windows are `always on top` by default.
client.connect_signal("property::floating", function(c) c.ontop = c.floating end)
```